# Issue with smoothing out javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a javascript animation that transitions details on an event action - however, I am having an issue removing a certain rogue div.

I have my init function as follows:

```
var demo = (function(window, undefined) {

  function init() {

    _mapPolygons(pattern);

    _bindCards();

    $(document.getElementsByClassName("card__overlay")).addClass(CLASSES.overlayHidden);

  };

   return {
     init: init
   };

})(window);

window.onload = demo.init;
```

The full snippet is here:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Demo.
 */
var demo = (function(window, undefined) {

  /**
   * Enum of CSS selectors.
   */
  var SELECTORS = {
    pattern: '.pattern',
    card: '.card',
    cardImage: '.card__image',
    cardClose: '.card__btn-close',
  };

  /**
   * Enum of CSS classes.
   */
  var CLASSES = {
    patternHidden: 'pattern--hidden',
    polygon: 'polygon',
    polygonHidden: 'polygon--hidden',
    overlayHidden: 'overlay--hidden',
  };

  /**
   * Map of svg paths and points.
   */
  var polygonMap = {
    paths: null,
    points: null
  };

  /**
   * Container of Card instances.
   */
  var layout = {};

  /**
   * Initialise demo.
   */
  function init() {

    // For options see: https://github.com/qrohlf/Trianglify
    var pattern = Trianglify({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      cell_size: 90,
      variance: 1,
      stroke_width: 0.6,
      color_function : function(x, y) {
        return '#f0f3f5';
      }
    }).svg(); // Render as SVG.

    _mapPolygons(pattern);

    _bindCards();

    $(document.getElementsByClassName("card__overlay")).addClass(CLASSES.overlayHidden);

  };

  /**
   * Store path elements, map coordinates and sizes.
   * @param {Element} pattern The SVG Element generated with Trianglify.
   * @private
   */
  function _mapPolygons(pattern) {

    // Append SVG to pattern container.
    $(SELECTORS.pattern).append(pattern);

    // Convert nodelist to array,
    // Used `.childNodes` because IE doesn't support `.children` on SVG.
    polygonMap.paths = [].slice.call(pattern.childNodes);

    polygonMap.points = [];

    polygonMap.paths.forEach(function(polygon) {

      // Hide polygons by adding CSS classes to each svg path (used attrs because of IE).
      $(polygon).attr('class', CLASSES.polygon + ' ' + CLASSES.polygonHidden);

      var rect = polygon.getBoundingClientRect();

      var point = {
        x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,
        y: rect.top + rect.height / 2
      };

      polygonMap.points.push(point);
    });

    // All polygons are hidden now, display the pattern container.
    $(SELECTORS.pattern).removeClass(CLASSES.patternHidden);
  };

  /**
   * Bind Card elements.
   * @private
   */
  function _bindCards() {

    var elements = $(SELECTORS.card);

    $.each(elements, function(card, i) {

      var instance = new Card(i, card);

      layout[i] = {
        card: instance
      };

      var cardImage = $(card).find(SELECTORS.cardImage);
      var cardClose = $(card).find(SELECTORS.cardClose);

      $(cardImage).on('click', _playSequence.bind(this, true, i));
      $(cardClose).on('click', _playSequence.bind(this, false, i));

    });
  };

  /**
   * Create a sequence for the open or close animation and play.
   * @param {boolean} isOpenClick Flag to detect when it's a click to open.
   * @param {number} id The id of the clicked card.
   * @param {Event} e The event object.
   * @private
   *
   */
  function _playSequence(isOpenClick, id, e) {

    var card = layout[id].card;

    // Prevent when card already open and user click on image.
    if (card.isOpen && isOpenClick) return;

    // Create timeline for the whole sequence.
    var sequence = new TimelineLite({paused: true});

    var tweenOtherCards = _showHideOtherCards(id);

    if (!card.isOpen) {
      // Open sequence.

      sequence.add(tweenOtherCards);
      sequence.add(card.openCard(_onCardMove), 0);

    } else {
      // Close sequence.

      var closeCard = card.closeCard();
      var position = closeCard.duration() * 0.8; // 80% of close card tween.

      sequence.add(closeCard);
      sequence.add(tweenOtherCards, position);

    }
    sequence.play();
  };

  /**
   * Show/Hide all other cards.
   * @param {number} id The id of the clcked card to be avoided.
   * @private
   */
  function _showHideOtherCards(id) {

    var TL = new TimelineLite;

    var selectedCard = layout[id].card;

    for (var i in layout) {

      var card = layout[i].card;

      // When called with `openCard`.
      if (card.id !== id && !selectedCard.isOpen) {
        TL.add(card.hideCard(), 0);
      }

      // When called with `closeCard`.
      if (card.id !== id && selectedCard.isOpen) {
        TL.add(card.showCard(), 0);
      }
    }

    return TL;
  };

  /**
   * Callback to be executed on Tween update, whatever a polygon
   * falls into a circular area defined by the card width the path's
   * CSS class will change accordingly.
   * @param {Object} track The card sizes and position during the floating.
   * @private
   */
  function _onCardMove(track) {

    var radius = track.width / 2;

    var center = {
      x: track.x,
      y: track.y
    };

    polygonMap.points.forEach(function(point, i) {

      if (_detectPointInCircle(point, radius, center)) {
        $(polygonMap.paths[i]).attr('class', CLASSES.polygon);
      } else {
        $(polygonMap.paths[i]).attr('class', CLASSES.polygon + ' ' + CLASSES.polygonHidden);
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Detect if a point is inside a circle area.
   * @private
   */
  function _detectPointInCircle(point, radius, center) {

    var xp = point.x;
    var yp = point.y;

    var xc = center.x;
    var yc = center.y;

    var d = radius * radius;

    var isInside = Math.pow(xp - xc, 2) + Math.pow(yp - yc, 2) <= d;

    return isInside;
  };

  // Expose methods.
  return {
    init: init
  };

})(window);

// Kickstart Demo.
window.onload = demo.init;
```

)

I'm essentially adding a class which should completely hide a div element, for which I have overkilled due in part to major frustrations:

```
.overlay--hidden {
    display: none !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

So this should completely kill the card__overlay div. I have added the same css "stylings" within the inspector and it works as should.

```
<div class="card__content card__overlay">
    <div class="card__caption">
        <p class="card__subtitle overlay">NEWS</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My issue is that essentially the getElementsByClassName method in the init function doesn't seem to be working - the class I want which is essentially hiding the div is not being added!

Comment: Your title says you have an issue with animation, but text in your question says you are having an _"issue removing a certain rogue div"_ which is it? Also you do not explain either problem, you just say you have one.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Hi Patrick - quite true. I often fumble on my choice of words. Essentially, what I have in the unit function isn't removing the div that I'm selecting (it's a minor part in the overall animation).

Comment: Have you looked at the console for errors? Have you checked that part of the code is actually being executed? Note you could just do `$(".card__overlay")` instead of trying to call getElementsByClassName and then passing it to jQuery

Comment: @PatrickEvans Hmmmm...ok, just tried that suggestion - it seems to have worked, just added it and it has completely removed the div on load. I just need to figure out how to add it to the sequence :/

Comment: @PatrickEvans Got it! :) Amazing how a small snippet such as the above can just help. Thank you.